# Density perturbation equation

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, perturbation-theory, structure-formation

I have seen people deriving:

$$\ddot{\delta} + 2 H \dot{\delta} - 4 \pi G \rho \delta=0 \ ,$$

from combining [Continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation), [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation) and [Euler equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)). I wanted to derive it from the perturbed $00$ and trace components of [Einstein's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) (within [Newtonian gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_gauge)).

Here they are:

\begin{align*}
\text{Poisson equation} \quad \nabla^2 \Phi &= 4\pi G a^2 \rho \delta & \text{(1)} \\ \\
\text{Trace part of EE} \quad \Phi'' + 3\mathcal{H}\Phi' + (2\mathcal{H}' + \mathcal{H}^2) \ \Phi &= 0 \ , & \text{(2)}
\end{align*}

where prime denotes a derivative with respect to conformal time.

Converting into coordinate time gives $$' = a\frac{d}{dt}, \quad '' = a^2\frac{d^2}{dt^2} + a\dot{a}\frac{d}{dt} \ .$$

Together, with $\mathcal{H} = a H$, the above equations transform into:

\begin{align}
\nabla^2 \Phi &= 4\pi G \rho \delta\\
\ddot{\Phi} + 4H \dot{\Phi} + (2\dot{H} + 3 H^2) \ \Phi &= 0\\
\end{align}

the rest follows as

[image]

I tried to find a mistake but I keep getting the same result. Could anyone please clarify what went wrong in my calculation?

Comment: Using $\ddot{\delta} + 2 H \dot{\delta} - 4 \pi G \rho \delta=0 \ $ and Poisson equation one obtains $\ddot{\Phi} + 8 H \dot{\Phi} + 9 H^2 \Phi = 0$ which is clearly not the same as Eq.2. But I believe the result should be identical regardless of the way the derivation is carried out.